# how to use 3 button texts in tkinter with an if statement

Tags: python, tkinter

i am making a naughts and crosses/ tic-tack-toe game in python tkinter, i have made it in quite a strange way where, thre is nine buttons in a grid and clicking on one changes the text to a 'o', however i am having trouble with using an if statement with 3 of the buttons to show that the user has won. there is no error message but the action is simply no being performed, and i can see no errors in the code
code-

```
if button3.cget('text') =='o'and button5.cget('text') =='o' and button7.cget('text') =='o':
    Label1 = Label(tk, text="you won")
    Label1.place(x=600 ,y=540)
```

Comment: _"i am having trouble"_ - what does that mean? What sort of trouble are you having? You haven't provide enough code for us to help. Please find a way to make a [mcve].

Comment: i meant that the if statement is simply not causing the action to be performed and if there was possibly any syntax errors.

Comment: If there were syntax errors, Python would have told you.  Either you aren't getting here, or the label isn't being seen.  Show us more of the code.

Comment: There are no syntax errors in your code, your code works fine. If the condition is true, you can be certain that the body of the `if` block will execute.